# PHP | Stripe API - check if customer have card attached

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up Stripe API to my website, but I ran into a problem. I need to check if the customer have a credit card attached to him, in order to process to subscribe to the plan.

I cannot seem to find anything about this in their docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer

The output from a customer looks like this:

```
Stripe\Customer JSON: {
  "id": "CUSTOMER_ID",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1474620297,
  "currency": "dkk",
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/CUSTOMER_ID/sources"
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/CUSTOMER_ID/subscriptions"
  }
}
```

So, how to check if the customer have a credit card attached to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customerID);
$cardID = $customer->default_source;

if(isset($cardID)){
    echo $cardID;
} else {
    echo "No card";
    //Code for entering card info..
}
```

There you will get the card id, and then you can simply check if you get something. If customer have a card then you get card id, if costumer does not have a card you won't get anything.

Comment: How do i check if it gets somethinfg?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cards = Customer::retrieve(STRIPE_CUSTOMER_ID)->sources->all([
    'object' => 'card'
])->data;
```

It  will return an array of card objects or an empty array if no cards exist.

```
if($cards == []) {
    // no cards exist for user
}
```